# how do i install a new version of my android game to my android device without overwriting the previous version?

Tags: android, copy, libgdx, duplicates

I have made many changes to my android game and want to install it to my device.

However, i do not wish to overwrite my previous version of the game, but instead, changing the name and installing that as well as keeping my original version
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: comes up with an error on this line -- <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: You have to change all the package names on your java class files as well.

Comment: that is a lot of hassle :( any easier way ? i have 20 classes, and around 8 packages

Comment: I know that changing the name is a pain. What is there a reason you want to keep the previous version? If you just want to keep the previous source code in case something breaks, I would recommend using some version control software like SVN or Git.